# Hit button many times, Animation stuck and Widget disappear

Tags: android

When I hit the buttons 5-6 times, the animation below stopped and Widget started to disappear or only showing half widget.

```
int blackViewStart = mBlackTextView.getTop();
        int blackVIewEnd = mBlackTextView.getBottom();
        ObjectAnimator blackAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mBlackTextView,"bottom",
                blackViewStart, blackVIewEnd);
        blackAnimator.setDuration(1000);

        int whiteViewStart = mWhiteTextView.getTop();
        int whiteViewEnd = mWhiteTextView.getBottom();
        ObjectAnimator whiteAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mWhiteTextView,"bottom",
                whiteViewStart, whiteViewEnd);
        whiteAnimator.setDuration(100);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playSequentially(blackAnimator,whiteAnimator);
        set.start();
    }
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: use boolean variable and use animation listener .Put your all animation in the if condition with boolean variable . And make boolean variable false when it clicked first time . And make that variable true when animation finish .